# clusterssh with multiple monitor

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The clusterssh is not working in Multiple Monitor case. I have 3 monitors configured for Ubuntu 10.10, which is working fine. But when using clusterssh 4.00.05-1 on it to manage multiple servers, it would display overlapping xterm windows, and it would require manual move to align those windows properly.

Does clusterssh support Multi-Monitor configuration? Anyone using it could shed some lights?

Answer (score 4):

I wont judge your needs and just will stick to an answer. I have the same problem as i got a second monitor today. 
My first and bigger and preferred monitor is 1680x1024 and it is on the left.
Second one is smaller and 1280x1024 and on the right.

I found out that there is a `.csshrc` file in my home directory. 
I changed `screen_reserve_right=0` parameter to 
**`screen_reserve_right=1280`**
and basically all the cssh windows stayed in my first monitor. Any custom need can be done with the parameters over there. Please `man cssh`, `FILES` part.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you want to use ClusterSSH?  In my experience it's not a good system management paradigm, because although you are executing the same command on multiple servers, you are still doing it manually.  This makes it very difficult to manage systems effectively in the long term.

Have you looked at a configuration management tool like [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com) or [Cfengine](http://www.cfengine.org)?  I strongly recommend you take the up-front time to configure one of these tools instead of manually applying changes with ClusterSSH.

I realize this doesn't directly answer your question but I think it's an important point to consider.

Comment: Yes. Thanks, I used both of them. But sometimes you would not be able to avoid manual work.

Comment: I never really found puppet to be worth the overhead for small numbers of machines. It's great for server farms and for deploying large numbers of desktops, but for 5 or 6 machines that are mostly unique but share a few similarities in config, it's more work than it's worth. You end up writing a puppet module and test it for one machine, then deploy it to the other 5 only to find the unique config on 2 of the machines prevented it from working there anyway. So now you're still SSHing into all 6 to verify things worked when you could have just run the commands manually and been done with it.